# Using Firebase in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to implement Firebase into my .NET WPF Desktop Application. I can't find anything useful on the internet about this topic, it seems like it's completely unsupported. There is only a Xamarin NuGet package.
Is there any possibility to do this? The goal is to implement Firebas Analytics for several actions the user makes in the app. 
I would even take the normal REST endpoints if I could find them - they are hidden somewhere...

The question is about Firebase Analytics, not Firebase Admin.

Comment: @Dominik it isn't as Firebase Admin is not Firebase Analytics. Plus, how can a question that is younger than the flagged one be a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, Maksym Labutin's answer tricked me that is why I did not realize that you are asking about Firebase Analytics.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use existing C# REST libraries like [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/) or [FirebaseSharp](https://github.com/bubbafat/FirebaseSharp)
or [Firebase Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) because official libraries do not exist yet.

P.S. [Firebase C# library](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18#.5j8zqmegj)

Comment: FirebaseSharp seems a bit outdated but I will have a look at FireSharp. Thanks! It's completely incomprehensible that Ruby is officially supported and .NET is not...

Comment: I think best solutions it's a use FireSharp. and simple docs https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/wiki/v1-Docs

Comment: yep ;) but this library open source and it's a big plus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133272/discussion-between-chris579-and-taras-kovalenko).

Comment: Firebase now has it's  own official library Firebase Admin SDK, I use it got it from nuget

Answer (score 20):

Google now provides an **official** .NET client: [Google.Cloud.Firestore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Firestore)

For tips on getting started, see their [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#c).

Answer (score 8):

Firebase also has it own library [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

[nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAdmin/)

Answer (score 0):

I use this fantastic library of firebase.

install via NuGet

> Install-Package PushNotification_dotNET -Version 1.0.0

[PushNotification_dotNET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushNotification_dotNET/)