# How to get data from firebase in c# mvc web project?

Tags: c#, firebase

I am building a website using c# mvc and firebase. Is there any methods to access firebase data from c# controller?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676797/8094831

That answer provides a list of several libraries to choose from:

- FireSharp - An asynchronous .Net client library for Firebase
- FirebaseSharp - A C# client for Firebase.io
- firebase-database-dotnet - C# library for Firebase Realtime Database
- Firebase Database REST API - The REST API for Firebase