# connect MySQL with Firebase

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, integrate

Currently I am creating a dashboard website by using MySQL as my database. Now, I need to get some data from Firebase which connected to my Android app. Anyone has any ideas on how to doing this kind of stuffs?

It seems like not much of this solution shown up after surfing through Internet.

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that Firebase uses NoSQL database technology. So you can't create tables and fields in Firebase at self. But you could make a workaround which fetches the data from Firebase and processing by a script on your web server and runs an SQL command to your MySQL database.

The technical part can be the language of your choice. Usually, in combination with MySQL, you use PHP. Here are an [SDK and documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) about how to implement it in that language.

From this SDK you could now [fetch data](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html#retrieving-data) from Firebase and store it via an SQL command to your MySQL database.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. If I understand you correctly, after I store data from Android to Firebase, a script(PHP) should be triggered to store the same data into MySQL. Is it that's all what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, so you could set up a cronjob on server side to fetch the data every minute.

Comment: by the way, what language is most suitable for me beside PHP because I am C#/C++ based and I never learn PHP before.

Comment: In this thread they discussed also about .NET library https://stackoverflow.com/q/41676714/5508719

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, appreciated! I will surely try it out!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer if this answer was helpful for you :).