# how to connect to Firestore Database using C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been stuck on connecting Firestore database to C# apps. I've been trying to find tutorial videos and other instructions online and seem unable to get what I need. please help me connect the app and be able to query or insert records to Firestore from my C# app. thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: Is your question how to connect to firebase? Or just how to query the database?

Comment: at this time, I guess it is how to connect

Comment: Okay you should edit your question to reflect that, or else people will start answering the wrong questions

Comment: done. any idea how to connect?

Comment: Try using this. I only use firebase in Android development currently so I don't have any experience with this. Hope it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676714/using-firebase-in-net

Comment: it doesn't clearly give some clear instructions.

Comment: actually it helped now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/userguide.html but seems still in Beta, many features are not supported

Comment: The problem with this example is it doesn't show how to pass in credentials and establish the connection.  I assumes we're already connected.  Been looking all over for how to connect

Comment: No longer beta. This answer is outdated.