# C# how can I sign up and sign in to Firebase with Email and Password Authenticate?

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make an application that can any user sign up and sign in to his account using **Firebase Email and Password Authenticate**

so I can see the list of users here (image)

[image]

I can do it with android but are there any ways to do it with c#?

**Now I know about the Firebase libraries but I want the code to do:**

**-`CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword`**

**-`SignInWithEmailAndPassword`**

**-`SendPasswordResetEmail`**

Answer (score -2):

You can use existing C# REST libraries like [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/) or [FirebaseSharp](https://github.com/bubbafat/FirebaseSharp) Or [Firebase Database](http://Firebase%20Database) REST API.

Because official library not exists, yet.

P.S. [Firebase C# library](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18#.5j8zqmegj)

[Using Firebase in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676714/using-firebase-in-net)

Comment: thank you.but how can I use those libraries to make sign up and login in C#.I mean the **code**