# Firebase with .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed my app in .net and now I need hosting and storage, but for that reason I have decided to use Firebase. I need help to be able to implement it in my app. Thank you very much in advance

I have configured my project with Firebase and have published it, but I can't find the tools to store and interact with the database inside my app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Firebase in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676714/using-firebase-in-net)